# WinDbg - getting the address of the last loaded PE into an Alias

Tags: debugging, windbg

I need to get the address of the last loaded PE, into the debugged process, into an *Alias* / register.

There's no problem to perform this action manually in a *WinDbg* session, using `lm` command, and then just to manually copy the address of the loaded module -- but this has to be a part of a *WinDbg script*.

I can pass the PE's name, full path, pdb path to *WinDbg* as arguments without a problem. But I doesn't seem to find a way to get the address, without copying it manually, into an *Alias*.
Maybe there's a way to address the last loaded module's address? (maybe through a specific register, which holds this value)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe the answer is really just that simple: the name of the module is already the address, so there's no additional need to find it out.

```
0:006> lm m notepad*
Browse full module list
start    end        module name
011f0000 0145c000   notepad__   (deferred)             

0:006> ? notepad__
Evaluate expression: 18808832 = 011f0000

0:006> as lastloaded notepad__

0:006> ? lastloaded
Evaluate expression: 18808832 = 011f0000
```

If (for whatever reason) you need it as a number, use `.printf`:

```
0:006> as /c xx .printf "%d", notepad__
0:006> .echo ${xx}
18808832

0:006> as /c xxh .printf "%x", notepad__
0:006> .echo ${xxh}
11f0000
```

For me, the problem is rather on the emphasis of "last loaded". How would you figure this out from the list of `lm`? But since you say that's not a problem for you, I'll not consider this in my answer.

Comment: At the moment when I load the PE, I'm printing a specific debug message in my code, which fits the previously defined `.ocommand` pattern in the WinDbg open session -- so that my WinDbg script is executed *at the moment* when the PE is loaded. That's why it is pretty reliable that it is the last loaded application :) That's why I needed to "convert" the PE name to the address where it has been loaded to. I didn't know that the actual PE name can be used as an Alias to the actual load address. Thank you very much, as always :)